# C# i have List<object> with object values internally changed and now i want to remove

Tags: c#, list, addition

C# I have List with object values internally changed and now i want to remove that object what i mean is

```
class Strength {
  public int energy;
  public Strength(int energy) {
    this.energy = energy;
  }
  public void increment(){
    this.energy++;
  }
}

List<Strength> strengthList = new List<Strength>();

Strength strength = new Strength(10);

strengthList.Add(strength);

strength.increment();

strengthList.Remove(strength);
```

Will it remove the object strength from the strengthList?

Thanks for all the help in advance

Comment: I mean will it have some lind of reference so it deletes the right object i want to delete? or am i not understanding well? please help

Comment: In short, yes it will remove strength

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to know is how C# handles [equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx) of objects.

In your case, it will remove this object, because they have same reference. You might also override this behaviour in your class, so it is able to compare values of this class.

To add : [List.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) uses [EqualityComparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx). This will use either [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) if object implements it, or will fall back to standard [Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) and [Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx).

Comment: And to add, when you override equals and hashcode, at that point calling the increment and then trying to remove from the list will not remove that "strength" from the list

Comment: No. It will remove it. Most overrides to Equals check for reference identity first. And in this case, it would compare strength field, which will result in value equality too.

Comment: Of course it would remove it, the object inside the list is the same as the one you're trying to remove, so it doesn't matter if it uses reference comparison or value comparison in this case. The important question is if you're using value comparison, would it remove any other objects as well? for instance, if you add one with value 1, and one with value 2, then increase the first up to have a value of 2, then ask the list to remove it. Then it would remove both (assuming List uses value comparison, I didn't bother to check.)

Comment: Yes. Remove will remove first element, that is equal. So if you have value equality implemented, and another element with same value, then it will delete it.